# Comparing data/means from different surveys - same question, different likert scales

Tags: data-transformation, likert, scales

I am trying to compare data from the same series of questions that most recently was used with a 5 point scale, but the previous iteration of it used a 7 point scale. Is there a way for me to convert/scale the means from the 7 point scale so that I can compare the means for the 5 point?